# Network File Share

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, file, delete, network

This should be an easy question but I've found nothing on Google that gives me a good idea:  What do you do with files on the Network File Share after they have been uploaded to SharePoint?  Is it best practice to delete them (which seems like the logical thing to do to me)?

Just beginning to explore what to "SharePoint" and what to keep on our file server.  Nervous to just go on an upload and delete spree.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uncomfortable with deleting the folders off a file share immediately after migrating to SharePoint, simply mark the folders as read only to prevent users from modifying the files. Once you've become comfortable with that, you can then revoke everyone's access to the folders and then delete it at a further date.

If the concern is hoarding, then you need to communicate a clear migration process. "The file share will be migrated to SharePoint on XX and at that point the share will be read only. This will allow for XX week(s) of data validation by both IT and business users. On XX-XX-XXXX, the data will be deleted from the file share."

We have also used written sign-offs of the data by the owners that they've reviewed the SharePoint site and confirm they have what they need. If they sign off early, we kill it early. If they don't sign off by the deadline, then we can determine what happens (like revoking all access versus deleting).

Comment: Updated with an example of what we have done, we have hoarding problems, but people are sensitive about their things.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience it is better to delete these files, otherwise you are going to manage the same file at 2 location and also confuse your customer which is real updated version and which is not.

Some user pick the file from FileShare then work on it and some user check the file from the SharePoint and update it.

In SharePoint you have the Checkin/Out function, versioning and better way to manage the permission. I think it is better to deal with SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing that I've done in the past where the file server was a virtual machine was have it backed up (or even just back up the file share itself) and then once a specific folder has been migrated, delete the contents and replace it with a TXT file named MOVED TO SHAREPOINT and in the file we copied the URL for the particular document library so users knew which folders were moved and which folders hadn't been moved yet.

Comment: Thanks to all for your helpful comments.  Our shared drive is a mess, as I'm sure you've all experienced.  Transitioning to Sharepoint sounds easy but it is way more complicated than it seems.